# what is for <excluded> tag in maven pom.xml file ?

Tags: xml, maven

I know we use `<exclusion>` `<excludes>` `<exclude>`tags in maven pom.xml. I had to add a `jarmodule` to the maven pom file like below.

```
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                        <excluded>true</excluded>
                    </jarModule>
```

What is the `<excluded>` tag means there ? 
This was added to the below plugin.

```
 <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
             .........................
```

Answer (score 1):

quote from the docs excluded - set to true to exclude this artifact from being packaged into the ear archive. Default is false.`. This is used if you have defined it as a dependency but don't like to be packed into the ear.

Comment: so are all those tags the same ? `<exclusion> <excludes> <exclude>` tags ?

Answer (score -1):

The use of  tag is to remove the artifact from your packaged ear.